# how to add a event to a telerik control from a master page

Tags: asp.net, telerik

If I add the event to the RadDatePicker  control then obviously it works

```
<telerik:RadDatePicker runat="server" ID="MyRadDatePicker" ClientEvents-OnDateSelected="clientEvent" />
```

.
.

**But My question is how** do I add the event "ClientEvents-OnDateSelected" from the code behind of my master page when the radDatePicker is in a custom control and that control is on the master page?

I tried this but it wont work?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
UC1MyCustomControl.FindControl("MyRadDatePicker").ClientEvents-OnDateSelected="clientEvent";

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cast the result of `FindControl` so you can access properties specific to `RadDatePicker`, and change the `-` in the attribute to `.`:

```
var datePicker = (RadDatePicker)UC1MyCustomControl.FindControl("MyRadDatePicker");
datePicker.ClientEvents.OnDateSelected = "clientEvent";
```

Instead of relying on `FindControl`, though, it might be better for the user control to expose the date picker as a public property:

```
// Inside the code-behind for the user control...
public RadDatePicker DatePicker
{
    get { return MyRadDatePicker; }
}
```

Using this property, the master page can access the date picker easily:

```
UC1MyCustomControl.DatePicker.ClientEvents.OnDateSelected = "clientEvent";
```

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Michaels answer. Best way is to for the custom control to expose the DatePicker as a property and the Master Pager can use that property to set the required events.